# Using strip() to removed double quotes

Tags: python, strip

Need help to strip double quotes from the variable a

```
>>> a
' "AZ-EDH"'
```

when following command is executed then only last double quotes are stripped

```
>>> a.strip('"')
' "AZ-EDH'
```

whereas when any of the following command is executed then both spaces & double quotes are stripped.

```
>>> a.strip('" ')
'AZ-EDH'

>>> a.strip(' " ')
'AZ-EDH'

>>> a.strip(' "')
'AZ-EDH'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're confusing `str.strip` and `str.replace`. `str.strip` removes *leading* and *trailing* characters (usually whitespace). What you want is probably `a.replace('"', '')`

Comment: From Python docs - "`str.strip([chars])` - Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed." Why do you expect it to remove anything in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `str.strip()` only removes leading and trailing characters.

The first `"` in `' "AZ-EDH"'` is not a leading character because of the space.

The optional parameter is a set of characters to remove. This means your examples of `' "'`, `'" '`, `' " '` are identical in meaning. They remove all leading `"` and  .

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html

You might be looking for `str.replace('"', '')`.

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/replace.html

Answer (score 2):

`str.strip()` only removes leading/trailing characters, if you want to remove all occurrences of a character, use `str.replace()` instead:

```py
>>> a=' "AZ-EDH"'
>>> a.replace('"', '')
' AZ-EDH'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = '"AZ-EDH"'
>>>'"AZ-EDH"'

A.replace('"', '')
>>>'AZ-EDH'
```

**.replace** function in python would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in `str.strip` method

```
strip(self, chars=None, /)
    Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed.

    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

for the case:

```
>>> a.strip('"')
' "AZ-EDH'
```

you have provided the character `"` only , so it wont strip space from start. and this resulting into  `"AZ-EDH`

and in other cases you have provided the space also, this you are getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace instead:

> > > a.replace(chr(34),'')